# How to correctly acquire resources with conditionally-initialised objects in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a number of classes which I've provided with an `Init()` function. Given a programmer using this code may forget to call `Init()`, or might call the destructor before `Init()`, I have written my destructor to check the state of the object. I feel this is not very well written and want to move away from this if possible, by initialising and allocating everything needed in the constructor (Scott Meyers recommends against initialisation methods, too). I have however been struggling to find a way to do this when using optional arguments/multiple constructors.

Current code:

```
class A {
    Init(B* some_other_object);
    Init(B* some_other_object, C* an_optional_argument);
    ...
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    A a;
    if(somecase)
        a.Init(b1, c1);
    else
        a.Init(b1);
}
```

Desired code:

```
class A {
    explicit A(B* some_other_object);
    A(B* some_other_object, C* an_optional_argument);
    ...
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    if(somecase)
        A a(b1, c1);
    else
        A a(b1);
}
```

Of course the issue here is that variable `a` goes out of scope immediately. And so I resort to allocating to the heap.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    A* a;
    if(somecase)
        a = new A(b1, c1);
    else
        a = new A(b1);
    ...
    delete a;
}
```

Which is not great if I was aiming to keep this on the stack. I've also considered the following

```
A a(b1, somecase?c1:nullptr);
```

Then shifting the conditional component into the body of a single constructor. This doesn't seem terribly elegant. Is there a better technique way of doing what I'm trying to do here? Preferable giving me the option of allocating A on the stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator for this. It allows you to do things that you cannot do with an `if-else`, for example. Assuming this simple class with two constructors,

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(int) {}
  Foo(int, int) {}
};
```

you can *initalize* an instance of the class based on a condition like this:

```
int i = ....;

Foo f = (i==42) ? Foo(42) : Foo(1, 2);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I think I may take this approach in my code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
A handleSomeCase(bool someCase, B *b1, C *c1) {
    if(somecase)
        return A(b1, c1);
    else
        return A(b1);
}

int main() {
    ...
    A a = handleSomeCase(someCase, b1, c1);
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Am I right in thinking A will be copied, here? Or will copy elision prevent that from happening?

Comment: @rod Copy/move elision can eliminate all copies and moves here. [example](http://ideone.com/jUcuW3)

Answer (score 1):

Since too long functions are never good, instead of delayed initialization with `Init()` and this code:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    A a;
    if(somecase)
        a.Init(b1, c1);
    else
        a.Init(b1);
}
```

you could initialize your instance of `A` with appropriate constructor in its scope, just decompose your code a little bit more:

```
void caseA(B* b1, C* c1) {
    A a(b1, c1);
    ...
}

void caseB(B* b1) {
    A a(b1);
    ...
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    if(somecase)
        caseA(b1, c1);
    else
        caseB(b1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
C* c1 = null; // by default
if (somecase)
    c1 = new C(); // (etc: I don't know where your C object comes from!)

// Now there's only 1 place you create this object, which is far cleaner    
A a(b1, c1);
```

And additionally (not that it applies in my code above) add a default argument and then have a single constructor for `class A`:

```
 A(B* some_other_object, C* an_optional_argument = null);
```

Comment: This is my current approach. The last example in my original post: A a(b1, somecase?c1:nullptr); was along these lines. I was trying to work out how I could do it without passing null arguments. But perhaps I'm overthinking this. In your words, it doesn't sound like too bad an option after all.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is copyable, you can do the following:

```
 class A
 {
 public:
     A();
     A(B* b);
     A(B* b, C* c);

     // you'll likely want to specify pointer ownership semantics
     A& operator=(const A& a);
 };

 A a;
 if(somecond)
     a = A(b);
 else
     a = A(b, c);
```

To further avoid pointer ownership problems, consider std::shared_pointer instead of bare pointers during an object copy.

Comment: Very clever indeed. Although it seems to me this still has the Init() problem: namely, if the programmer uses this incorrectly and the destructor gets called immediately after the first initialisation, we still need a smart destructor. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: @rod, just make your default constructor leave the object "empty". If no part of it gets set up, there's nothing to tear down.

Answer (score 0):

If A has a sensible default state, I don't see what's wrong with your original method. It's analogous to the following code

```
string s;
if (x)
{
    s = "hi";
}
else
{
    s = "bye";
}
```

The problem is if you have half-constructed objects floating around. A fully constructed, but not yet containing useful data, object is fine (in my humble opinion)

Comment: From the OP it sounds like the initial state is not sensible; That's why he has to check in the destructor if the object has been put into a reasonable state by Init() or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are working with pointers move the conditions inside the class and away from the users with a default value for the parameter.

```
class A {
    A(B* some_other_object, C* an_optional_argument = NULL) {
        if(an_optional_argument) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
    }
    ...
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    A a(b1);
    A b(b1, c1);
}
```